# jQuery - Bind Multiple Functions To One Event But Differentiate Execution of Functions

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, resize

I have two different functions bound to one element and event, basically they are called upon 'mousedown'.

I'm trying to figure out a way to allow my element to 'resize' or 'move/drag' but not both at the same time.

Right now I am using a 'setTimeout' function that is cleared when the 'resize' function is called, by doing this I cancel my 'move/drag' function. It works but not very well at all.

**I need help figuring out a better way. I appreciate any suggestions.**

```
var timer= "",
    resize_select = false;

$('element').resize(function() {
    resize_select = true;
    //do stuff, called every resize, just like resizing <textarea> 
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
});

$('element').on("mousedown", function() {
    $(this) = $this;
    resize_select = false;

    if (resize_select === false) {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $this.addClass('dragable');
        }, 500);
    }

    $(document).on("mousemove", function(e) {
        $('.dragable').css({
            top: e.pageY,
            left: e.pageX
        });
    });
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function() {
    resize_select = false;
    $('.resize').removeClass('dragable');
});
```

I am using Ben Alman's 'jQuery resize event' to allow any element to bind to .resize();

**[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/WHH5V/32/)** is a jsfiddle of where I am currently at.

---

**UPDATED**

```
$('.resize').css({
    resize:'both',
    overflow:'hidden'
});

$('.resize').on('mousedown', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $this_height = $this.height(),
        $this_width = $this.width(),
        x = event.pageX - $this.offset().left,
        y = event.pageY - $this.offset().top,
        xx = $this_width - 10,
        yy = $this_height - 10,
        img_num = $(this).index();

    event.preventDefault();

    if (xx - x > 0 || yy - y > 0) {
        $(document).mousemove(function(pos) {
            var thisX = pos.pageX - $this_width / 2,
                thisY = pos.pageY - $this_height / 2;

            $this.offset({
                left: thisX,
                top: thisY
            })
        });
    }

    if (xx - x < 0 && yy - y < 0) {
        $(document).mousemove(function(pos) {
            var thisX = pos.pageX - $this.offset().left,
                thisY = pos.pageY - $this.offset().top,
                ratio = ((thisX + thisY) / 2) / (($this_height + $this_width) / 2),
                height_new = $this_height * ratio,
                width_new = $this_width * ratio;

            $this.css({
                'width': width_new,
                'height': height_new
            });
        });
    }
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function() {
    $(document).unbind('mousemove');
});
```

this works due to @jfriend00 for the idea of figuring out where in each element the 'mousedown' event happens & to @Jeremy C providing various optimizations.

js fiddle here [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/WHH5V/47/)

Comment: You will have to have only one event handler and then use the code in that to decide which other functionality to execute.  It isn't easy to try to cancel the execution of some other event handler from a different event handler and it's impossible if one of the event handlers postpones it's decision on a timer.

Comment: @jfriend00     I understand, thank you for your reply. I just don't know how to go about it. If you had any recommendations or references on how to detect a 'resize' within the browser I could figure it out.

Comment: What is your criteria for determining whether it's a resize or a drag?  I would guess that it has to do with where the mousedown occurs (in middle of object or on edge).  If so, can't you just set a flag on the mousedown based on where the initial mouse event occurs and then in the mousemove events after that flag occurs, you can look at the flag and decide how to handle the move events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a timer at all. This works on Chrome at least, I would test in all browsers to be safe. Here ya go:

```
var img_amount = $('.resize').length,
    height_org = new Array(),
    width_org = new Array(),
    resize_select = false,
    timer = "";

for (var i = 0; i < img_amount; i++) {
    height_org[i] = $('.resize:eq(' + i + ')').height();
    width_org[i] = $('.resize:eq(' + i + ')').width();
}

//set div width to div height * ratio to preserve aspect ratio
$('.resize').resize(function(event){
    var img_num = $(this).index(),
        height_new = $(this).height(),
        ratio = height_new / height_org[img_num],
        width_new = width_org[img_num] * ratio;

    $(this).css('width', width_new);
});

$('.resize').on('mousedown', function(event) {
    //prevent typical browser behaviour of dragging the div as an image
    event.preventDefault();

    //set z-index so the div you are dragging is in front
    $('.resize').css('z-index', 1);
    $(this).css('z-index', 2);

    $(this).mousemove(setPos);
});

$('.resize').on('mouseup', function() {
    $(this).unbind('mousemove', setPos);
});

function setPos(event) {
    var thisX = event.pageX - $(this).width() / 2;
    var thisY = event.pageY - $(this).height() / 2;
    $(this).offset({
        left: thisX,
        top: thisY
    });
}
```

EDIT: I added the resize function to restrict the aspect ratio with css 'resize: vertical', however it's a bit jumpy looking. To make it really smooth I would say create your own resize hit area on the bottom right of each div, add a png to it to mimic the browser resize handle and then create your own resize on drag function instead of using the css resize.

Comment: +1 works in Chrome/FF/IE9, however seems like you removed the `resize` handler which is used to keep the aspect ratio when resizing.

Comment: @Jeremy C      Believe you removed resize functionality all together... Wanted to Resize & Move but not at the same time.

Comment: I'll add it back, didn't realize you were restricting size ratio.

Comment: @Terry - the javascript resize function is not enabling the resizing, it's just restricting the aspect ratio, resizing is enabled by the css property 'resize: vertical', however, as in my edit note, I would consider doing it just in js to make it look smooth. It's jumpy because the browser refreshes the screen with new size faster than the jQuery resize event fires. See the updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WHH5V/41/

Comment: @Jeremy C      Thanks a bunch dude, really really appreciate it. I'm gonna write my own little resize function now and scrap the plugin I'm using. It was convenient for the time being but it looks like junk, your right.